# Why do some people assigning JavaScript variables like var example = window.example || {};

Tags: javascript

I been seeing people assigning JavaScript variables such as:

```
var example = window.example || {};
```

And I am wondering the reason for this. And yes I am already aware that || is the OR operator and {}; is a object literal.

Would be great if someone could answer, thanks!

Comment: If you know what `||` does, then you have all the facts you need. What if `window.example` is undefined? What if it has a value already?

Comment: I see. So, if I wanted it to be a array literal I could go: var example = window.example || [];? It's not just for object literals right?

Comment: Yes, an array is fine. You can do this with any variable types, including different types on the left and right sides of the `||`, e.g., `var example = someNumber || someString;`

Comment: And another thing, can this be used in variables declared in a function? Wouldn't it be kind of like: var example = window.functionExampleIsDeclaredIn.example || {};?

Answer (score 4):

[Short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) exploitation and the fact JavaScript returns the last expression evaluated.

If the LHS is *truthy*, then the entire expression is satisfied (it's an `||`) and JavaScript returns the LHS.

If the LHS is *falsy*, then the RHS needs to be evaluated, because it is on the other side of the logical or operator (`||`). Even if the RHS is *falsy*, it is returned because it is the last expression evaluated.

It is typically used to provide default argument values for functions...

```
var sayHello = function(name) {
    name = name || 'Alex';
    alert('Hello ' + name);
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to describe what "Short circuit evaluation exploitation means"?

Comment: @JamesHay The linked Wikipedia article has a wealth of information.

Comment: _"then the entire expression is `true`"_ - no, the entire expression is _truthy_ - if the entire expression was `true` that is what would be returned rather than the RH operand. (I know you know this, I'm just being picky about wording.)

Comment: @nnnnnn OK, I'll change it :)

Comment: "Satisfied"? Even better in the context of short-circuit evaluation. +1.

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly used when multiple scripts share a same object.

Each script includes the declaration:

```
var example = window.example || {};
```

When the first script runs, example doesn't exist, so the above expression creates an empty object (window.example evaluates as false)

Then the other scripts will reuse the existing element, as the first expression becomes true.

This is useful in particular if you don't know in which order your scripts will execute (asynchronous load or widgets that can be moved around).

[Edit] to follow up on your above comment, this could apply to other JavaScript objects:

```
Array: var exampleArray = window.exampleArray || [];

String: var exampleString = window.exampleString || "";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a shorthand syntax for

```
var example = (typeof window.example == 'undefined') ? {} : window.example;
```

Obviously, `window.example` is just the variable `example` anyway.

Note: This is **slightly** a lie - it doesn't test for "undefined", it tests for "not-truey" (empty string, 0, null, etc).

If `window.example` contains any truey value, `example` is set to that. If not (because it's not defined yet, for example), it gets given a default value of `{}` (empty object).

Comment: It's more shorthand for `var example = window.example ? window.example : {};`

Comment: Yep, but as we're on explaining things, let's make it as easy to understand as we can, eh? :)

Comment: Sure, but maybe change *shorthand syntax* for *typically used over the more verbose...*.

Comment: I'm not that nitpicky :) Feel free to edit it, but it just seems a bit too pedantic for me to worry about lol

Comment: "Not truey"? You mean "falsy"?

Comment: Anybody else want to take a potshot at something that doesn't really have anything wrong with it? :)